# Incorrect syntax near 'month' with dynamic number

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

While running this query

```
update p_leave_allocation_14122015 
set 'month' + @actualMonth  = @actualleavedays
where year = @actualYear  
  and emp_card_no = @emp_card_no
```

I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'month'.

The table `p_leave_allocation_14122015` has columns like `month1`, `month2`, `month3`,**.....**

In my update query what I want is `month` will be hardcoded and the no of month will be dynamic based on some conditions which I have written.

But when I tried with the above query I got the mentioned error.

I am using SQL Server 2005.

Kindly suggest

Comment: You cannot parametrize column name like you proposed. You need to use Dynamic-SQL

Comment: @lad2025: OK, how to use that dynamic sql ?

Comment: This is usually a sign of a broken data model - some of what should be your *data* has instead ended up embedded in the *metadata* - here, the column and table names. You'll end up continually fighting with this sort of data model because there's no easy way to query this embedded data using normal SQL tools.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: then any other simple idea to proceed for this ?

Comment: It means you shouldn't be designing your tables like a paper form. The table probably ought to be pivoted to have more rows, and you'd end up with a column called `month` that contains a number between 1-12, and another column, called say `leavedays` that stores the data you're currently shoving into these `monthX` columns. You'd then have up to twelve *rows* of data that is straightforward to query and update, with no need for dynamic SQL.

Comment: I will just leave it as **[demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/413292?Month=11&LeaveDays=8)**

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Sir thanks for the information and sharing some useful knowledge. It will be good if u share some useful and related documents so that if next time I get this scenario I would handle this by my own

Comment: As always @lad2025 - solution is faster and good...

Comment: @lad2025: will this much code is enough for my SP, `DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(100) = 
N'update #p_leave_allocation_14122015 
set <col_name>  = @actualleavedays
where [year] = @actualYear  
 and [emp_card_no] =  @emp_card_no';
 
SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '<col_name>',
QUOTENAME('month' + CAST(@actualMonth AS VARCHAR(2))));` **taken from your solution**

Comment: @coder You need also `EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql]
      @sql,
      N'@actualleavedays INT, @actualYear INT, @emp_card_no VARCHAR(25)',
      @actualleavedays,@actualYear,@emp_card_no;` The code you proposed will have no effect without executing it. Probably the query will need some kind of workaround because SQL Server 2005 is quite limited comparing to newer versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You should try something like below*,

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'update p_leave_allocation_14122015 
           SET MONTH'+CAST(@actualMonth AS VARCHAR(2)) +' = ' + CAST(@actualleavedays AS VARCHAR(10))+
           ' WHERE YEAR = '+ CAST(@actualYear AS VARCHAR(4))+
           ' AND emp_card_no = '+CAST(@emp_card_no AS VARCHAR(100)) +'';

PRINT @sql --Note: Check the query first before updating.
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql;
```

Comment: why nvarchar has been set to `1000` ? any reason for this ?

Comment: while executing the whole SP, I get error as `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'update p_leave_allocation_14122015 
      SET MONTH12 = 0 WHERE YEAR = ' to data type int.`

Comment: I've mentioned that we need to check the print query if it is not correct then we might have to make some changes in our query.

Comment: I've updated stil I'm checking my query...if anything wrong with my sql parameters... Done try now and let me know if any error is there...

Comment: is it necessary to run this line `EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql;` coz its already under the SP

Comment: now getting error as `Msg 8115, Level 16, State 6, Procedure Monthly_leave_Allocation_2016, Line 112
Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.`

Comment: Now that would be with your data. I don't have sample data. so sorry for that. BTW while using dynamic query it is needed `EXEC` OR `EXECUTE(@SQLStatement)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98558/discussion-between-coder-and-curiousguy).

Comment: thanks a lot, now it is working for me as expected.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `dynamic query` to do this

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max) = '' 

SET @sql = 'update p_leave_allocation_14122015       set month' 
           + Cast(@actualMonth AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' =  ' 
           + Cast(@actualleavedays AS VARCHAR(10)) 
           + ' where year = @actualYear  and emp_card_no =  @emp_card_no ' 

EXEC Sp_executesql 
  @sql, 
  N'@actualYear int,@emp_card_no int', 
  @actualYear, 
  @emp_card_no
```

Note: If `@actualMonth` or `@actualleavedays` is of `integer` type then you need to cast it to `varchar` to work in dynamic query

Comment: getting two errors,

1. `Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.`

2. `Must declare the scalar variable "@sqlleaveupdate".`

Comment: @sqlleaveupdate is never used in code. Post your full code

Comment: i have changed `sql` to `sqlleaveupdate` for my reference

Comment: then declare it before using `declare @sqlleaveupdate nvarchar(max) = ''`

Comment: The answer you chosen is wide open to sql injection. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @sql varchar(max)=''
declare @actualMonth int=10
declare @actualleavedays int=20
declare @actualYear int=2015
declare @emp_card_no varchar(8)='Emp1010'

set @sql = 'update p_leave_allocation_14122015 
             set month' + cast(@actualMonth as varchar(2))  + '='+ cast(@actualleavedays as varchar(3))+
           ' where year ='+ cast(@actualYear as varchar(4))  + 'and emp_card_no ='+  @emp_card_no

print @sql --check generated sql query  
exec(@sql)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

make a string and stored in `nvarchar` variable and then execute query like below

```
DECLARE @SqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SqlQuery ='update p_leave_allocation_14122015 set month' + @actualMonth + '=' + @actualleavedays + ' where year = '+  @actualYear + ' and emp_card_no ='+ @emp_card_no 
EXEC(@SqlQuery)
```